# How do I restart rather than recreate an Activity after a notification click in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some code that sends out a notification that a download is completed, when this notification is clicked, I want it to *restart* my activity.

Currently, the notification is created in a `BroadcastReceiver`. This is the section where I added the Intents to the notification.

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, CurrentActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK  );
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Right now what this does is destroy my `CurrentActivity` by calling the `onDestroy()` method, then calls `onCreate()` to create a new instance. This is an issue for me as my `onDestroy()` unbinds my BoundService from my activity. I would much rather have my Activity just restart (`onStop()` then `onRestart()` then `onStart()`) so my `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods can handle the binding and unbinding and my `onStart()` method handles the changes to the UI.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure (can't test it now), but I would suggest removing FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, see ->  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 3):

I think you might consider setting the intent flags differently to achieve the behavior that you want.

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Handle your UI changes in your `onResume` activity if required. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your activity flag to be

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

See the flag official document from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED

> If set, and this activity is either being started in a new task or bringing to the top an existing task, then it will be launched as the front door of the task. This will result in the application of any affinities needed to have that task in the proper state (either moving activities to or from it), or simply resetting that task to its initial state if needed.